# reliable mp3 splitting php class or any tool for linux

Tags: php, linux, mp3

I tried all php mp3 split classes that i found on the web but none of them can cut VBR encoded mp3 files or mp3 files containing artwork.

Then i tried to install [mpgtx](http://mpgtx.sourceforge.net/) but it could not be installed somehow, i got errors on while making package with "make" command.

any suggestion ?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried ffmpeg? http://www.qc4blog.com/?p=870

Comment: it is going good but what is that ? Encoder (codec id 86017) not found for output stream #0.0 , i got it when i wanted to split an mp3 file to new mp3 file. how can i install that codec ?

Comment: also i am getting [mp3 @ 0x8b06420]max_analyze_duration reached
[mp3 @ 0x8b06420]Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FFMPEG is amazing ! i am happy that i found it :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the mp3splt project on SourceForge?  That provides a command line utility and supports ID3v2 tags.

http://mp3splt.sourceforge.net/mp3splt_page/home.php

Note what the documentation says about VBR MP3s causing issues if they do not have appropriate headers set and to use the `-f` switch to enabled framemode in these cases.

Comment: yes i tried it today. i got errors on installing libmad that is required for installing mp3splt. it was saying "cannot find the library ../libltdl/libltdl.la" and i couldnt resolve this. :(

Comment: libltdl is part of libtool, that component can be distributed as part of applications.  Maybe download libtool to get the library you need. http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/